# Visual Studio 22 - Unable to save toolchainFile for VCPKG

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

When I open CMakePresets.json I see this:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "name": "Qt",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "$env{QTDIR}"
      },
      "environment": {
        "PATH": "$penv{PATH};$env{QTDIR}/bin"
      },
      "vendor": {
        "qt-project.org/Qt": {
          "checksum": "Sp19WUpde73JS7nK33HZMqVZTyI="
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "vendor": {
    "qt-project.org/Presets": {
      "checksum": "+knLrtcP3xTAxZGDu4uUoEIBvBs="
    }
  }
}
```

Than I simply try to add this: `"toolchainFile": "V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",` so the whole file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "hidden": true,
      "name": "Qt",
      "toolchainFile": "V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH": "$env{QTDIR}"
      },
      "environment": {
        "PATH": "$penv{PATH};$env{QTDIR}/bin"
      },
      "vendor": {
        "qt-project.org/Qt": {
          "checksum": "Sp19WUpde73JS7nK33HZMqVZTyI="
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "vendor": {
    "qt-project.org/Presets": {
      "checksum": "+knLrtcP3xTAxZGDu4uUoEIBvBs="
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment when I save it looks like VS22 just reloads and deletes the line `"toolchainFile": "V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake",` I have added.

It acts very weird.

I am sure I have VCPKG installed because of this:

```
PS V:\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.
CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=V:/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries. Linking will be handled automatically. Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.
```

So what is going on and how can I simply make Visual Studio 22 to recognize vcpkg for CMake projects ?
PS V:\vcpkg>